# java.io.IOException: Invalid argument at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0

Tags: eclipse, windows, tomcat, ioexception

I am using Eclipse Mars with Tomcat v8.0.30 ,jre 1.8.0_73. Yesterday I didnt have any problems but today my Tomcat server fail to start. A dialog pops up and it says: "Starting Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost has encountered a problem. Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

I have this error in the console:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap initClassLoaders
SEVERE: Class loader creation threw exception
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.createClassLoader(Bootstrap.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders(Bootstrap.java:146)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
```

I have Tomcat EE v7.0 server which gives me the exact same problem.
I reinstalled Eclipse and Tomcat , I restarted my PC , I restored default options multiple times. I created new server couple of times and I even deleted "org.eclipse.core.resources" and the result is still the same.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. I suspect your `CATALINA_HOME` is set wrong. Usually users writing `path\bin;` where it is `only-path-to-tomcat` without bin or any folder.
2. Remove backslash \ at the end of the `CATALINA_HOME`
3. You must check your tomcat log `catalina.out` to trace the route cause
4. Also check your TOMCAT_HOME/conf/catalina.properties file. There may be some unseen character that causes`java.io.IOException: Invalid argument`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i still get the same error. I checked CATALINA_HOME but thats not the issue. Can you please explain to me what should "check your tomcat log catalina.out to trace the route cause" mean?

Comment: Tomcat log is written in `TOMCAT_HOME/logs` directory. Check and copy paste it by updating question. In catalina.out you can find the main cause as to why your tomcat not starting

Comment: I just wrote a regex to check my catalina.properties file for symbols after ".jar" and before "," but there wasnt any. I checked my logs directory. It contains 5 log files - 3 of them empty. The localhost.2016-02-13.log file everything seems okay.It holds 4 lines which  end like this
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
I checked my catalina.log too but there isnt any problem there too.

Comment: It started! Thank you so much for your help but the problem was in my server properties. I fix it in eclipse and everything is fine. Thank you

Comment: How you fix it please share here so that other can get benefit and it may be a plus to my knowledge

Comment: I just had to specify the server path in "Server locations" to "Use Tomcat installation (takes control of tomcat installation)" ... its really dumb problem actually

Comment: happy to hear you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

If anybody facing this issue recently while using community server extension vscode[repo link](https://github.com/redhat-developer/rsp-server-community) , then it is because of the recent version update. The latest version 0.26.3 released on 4th March,2023 has some issues. Downgrade to the previous stable version 0.25.7 ,everything will work fine. It may be because of other issues as well, but this is the recent issue I have faced. I think it will solve problems for the one facing this recently.